# Is there an option to adjust the memory maximum in the spyder.ini?

Tags: python, eclipse, spyder

in some programs, I can adjust my memory usage upfront in the `.ini` .

E.g. in knime:

```
-vm
plugins/org.knime.binary.jre.win32.x86_64_1.8.0.152-01/jre/bin
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.4.0.v20161219-1356.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.551.v20171108-1834
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-server
-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false
...
-Xmx16384m
```

I can adjust it with `Xmx16384m` , so in this example around 16GB of RAM.

Does this also works in spyder? Somehow it is only using around 2GB of RAM, which is quite low.

```
icon_theme = spyder 3
opengl = software
single_instance = True
open_files_port = 21128
tear_off_menus = False
normal_screen_resolution = True
high_dpi_scaling = False
high_dpi_custom_scale_factor = False
high_dpi_custom_scale_factors = 1.5
vertical_dockwidget_titlebars = False
vertical_tabs = False
animated_docks = True
prompt_on_exit = False
panes_locked = True
window/size = (1920, 1018)
window/position = (-8, -8)
window/is_maximized = True
window/is_fullscreen = False
window/prefs_dialog_size = (745, 411)
show_status_bar = True
memory_usage/enable = True
memory_usage/timeout = 2000
cpu_usage/enable = False
cpu_usage/timeout = 2000
use_custom_margin = True
custom_margin = 0
use_custom_cursor_blinking = False
show_internal_errors = True
check_updates_on_startup = True
toolbars_visible = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) There's no such option to do that in Spyder and I don't know if it's even possible in Python, sorry.